# Help with proving existence of a certain set using Zorn's lemma

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As part of my homework I need to prove, using Zorn's lemma, that there exists a set $A \subseteq [0,1)$ so that for every real number $r \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a **single** element $a \in A$ that satisfies $r-a \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Here's what I've tried: first I defined a weak partial order $\prec$ that satisfies $A \prec B \iff B \subseteq A$. Then I defined a set $Q = \{A \subseteq [0,1) \mid \forall r \in \mathbb{R}~ \exists a \in A. r-a \in \mathbb{Q}\}$, proved it's not equal to $\emptyset$, and tried to find an upper bound for every chain $C \subseteq Q$. Here's where I got stuck. I thought $\cap C$ would work as an upper bound for every chain $C$, and I've managed to prove $\forall c \in C. c \prec \cap C$. The problem is I can't prove that $\cap C \in Q$, that is, for every $r \in \mathbb{R}$ exists $a \in \cap C$ so that $r-a \in \mathbb{Q}$. 
It seems to me that the way I defined the order, $\cap C$ should be **inside** $C$, but I can't prove that either.

Anyways, any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: FWIW I would prove this with a different formulation of the axiom of choice which says "surjections of sets are split." The map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ is surjective, so there is a map back and we can make the map land in $[0, 1]$ by modding by $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial order you want is simply set containment.  The sets you want are sets $B$ with the property that $\forall x, y \in B ~(y-x \notin \Bbb Q)$.  It’s obvious that the union of any chain with this property also has the property, so you have an upper bound and can apply Zorn’s Lemma to get a maximal element $A$.

$A$ is easily seen to satisfy the requirements.  If there were were two elements $x, y \in A$ with a rational difference from the same real $r$, then $(r-x)-(r-y)=y-x$ would be rational, contradicting the construction of $A$.  If there were some real $r$ that did not have a rational difference from any element of $A$, then the previous sentence shows that $A \cup \{r- \lfloor r \rfloor \}$ would contradict the maximality of $A$.